# how to use the function "copy" to assign a UTF-8 value to a variable

Tags: delphi-6

I use the following code to assign text to an SQL parameter:

```
quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('veh_type').value := copy(s,11,1);
```

Sometimes the text in the `.txt` file I am reading from is in UTF-8, which has characters using two bytes. How can I change the following code to accept UTF-8 data?

```
procedure TPrepareform.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f : textfile;
  s : string;
  i : integer;
  IsAnsiString : Boolean;
begin
  with quInsert do
  begin
    close;
    sql.clear;
    sql.add('insert into v_info_2018');
    sql.add('(record_type, plate_group, plate_no, v_type, v_type_cn,');
    sql.add('v_type_pt, v_type_pt, v_brand, engine_no, ct_tax_amount');
    sql.add('inspect_date, record_date');
    sql.add('values (:record_type, :plate_group, :plate_no, :v_type, :v_type_cn, :v_type_pt, :v_type_pt,');
    sql.add(':v_brand, :engine_no, :ct_tax_amount,');
    sql.add(':inspect_date, :record_date');
  end;
  i := 0;
  assignfile(f,edMasterName.Text);
  reset(f);
  while not eof(f) do
  begin
    readln(f,s);
    inc(i);
  end;
  prInsert.Max := i;
  i := 0;
  reset(f);
  VRS_Main.StatusBar1.Panels[5].Text:='0';
  while not eof(f) do
  begin
    inc(i);
    prInsert.StepIt;
    readln(f,s);
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('record_type').value := copy(s,1,1);
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('plate_group').value := copy(s,2,1);
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('plate_no').value := copy(s,3,8);
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('v_type').value := copy(s,11,1);
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('v_type_cn').value := UTF8Decode(copy(s,12,50));
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('v_type_pt').value := copy(s,62,50);
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('v_brand').value := copy(s,112,30);
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('engine_no').value := copy(s,142,50);
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('ct_tax_amount').value := copy(s,192,9);
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('inspect_date').value := copy(s,201,50);
    quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('record_date').value := copy(s,251,8);
    quInsert.ExecSQL;
    VRS_Main.StatusBar1.Panels[5].Text:=inttostr(strtoint(VRS_Main.StatusBar1.Panels[5].Text)+1);
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: What encoding does the database use? Is it even configured to accept Unicode?

Comment: it is windows sql server 2008 R2

Comment: Your SQL is malformed. On these two lines: `sql.add('inspect_date, record_date');` and `sql.add(':inspect_date, :record_date');`, you are missing a closing `)` after `record_date` and `:record_date`, respectively. Your SQL looks like this when executed: `'insert into v_info_2018 (<fields> values (<params>'`, when it should look like this instead: `'insert into v_info_2018 (<fields>) values (<params>)'` I'm surprised you are not getting a runtime error from the database about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the UTF-8 data in a `UTF8String` instead of a standard `String`, and then call either `UTF8Decode()` or `Utf8ToAnsi()` and store that result in the database.

Comment: hi, dear Remy, 

thank you for your answer, that's useful. 

tempstring := copy(s,12,50);
tempstring := UTF8Decode(tempstring);
quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('veh_type_cn').value := tempstring;

the second line temstring show the excatly "chinese text"
and when in the third line, quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('veh_type_cn').value still got the strange text, could u know why?

Comment: `UTF8Decode()` returns a UTF-16 `WideString`. Don't assign that back to your `tempString` (which is clearly an `(Ansi/UTF8)String`), that will just perform an unwanted UTF16->Ansi conversion. Assign the `WideString` directly to the `Value` and let the database handle any conversions it needs, eg: `quInsert.Parameters.ParamByName('v_type_cn').value := UTF8Decode(copy(s,12,50));` (BTW, in your question, you are calling `UTF8Encode()` instead of `UTF8Decode()`. Don't double-encode UTF data!)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP3l3.png

hi Remy, could u kindly help to see this pic, seems the value is still '?'

Comment: You are evaluating `Value` (a `Variant`) in the debugger. Maybe the tooltip evaluator in Delphi 6 doesn't handle Unicode strings very well? Who knows. You haven't shown the actual data you are working with, or what it looks like at each step. Did you validate that the `WideString` itself contains the correct data? What about the database after the insert? And you didn't answer David's questions. What database are you using? What character encoding does it use? These are important things to know.  Your data is going through several layers, data loss could occur at any one of them.

Comment: it is windows sql server 2008 R2